# Trigger google play services update, silently

Tags: background, google-play-services, auto-update

Is there a way to trigger google play services update in background. Need to do this as the potential users of the app will be complete noobs when it came to using android phone, so some things needs to made easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a setting inside of the Play Store app on the phone. Otherwise, no. You are unable to force that upon the user from the development side.